# Collision occurred in html page horizontal scroll and recyclerview vertical scroll

Tags: android, html, android-recyclerview, android-webview

I have a `WebView` in my `RecyclerView`, and the `WebView` loaded a html page. The part of the page can be horizontal scrolled, but when I horizontal scroll, the `RecyclerView` take the touch event easily and start to scroll vertically.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out the solution about my question. The part of the `WebView` is in the top of the view. so I use this to intercept the touch event:

```
float touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext()).getScaledTouchSlop()

webView.setOnTouchListener((View v, MotionEvent event) -> {
    if (!scrollFlag && event.getY() < getHeight() / 2) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (Math.abs(event.getY() - downY) < touchSlop && Math.abs(event.getX() - downX) > touchSlop) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    scrollFlag = true;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        scrollFlag = false;

    return false;
});
```

Comment: what is touchSlop @L. Swifter

Comment: I add the code about the `touchSlop`, @SamwinishereHere